# Enterprise Web Services Directory

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asmx, soa

The .NET enterprise system I work with, has disparate web-services all over the place.
Some of them with test stubs/benches and excellent maintenance...and many others without.

The objective is to aggregate all the web services (asmx & svc) together and have them under a live test bench with smoke tests & unit tests to ensure their functionality. Preferably in an automated way too.

Is there an service aggregation software/system that caters to this aspect in .NET? What would be the best approach?

Comment: Are you thinking of something that hunts down these services and "copies" them over to a test server?  Each service has independent deployment needs and processes, those would have to change to deployment to a test server.  If not, could you detail "aggregation" a little more?

Comment: Why is this situation different just because they are web services? Why not treat them exactly like any other code in your Enterprise?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "aggregate all the web services"? Do you want one "portal-web-service" that passes requests on, or just locate all of them, or have one hosting platform for all of them, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out [SO-AWARE](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=soaware&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware%25E2%2584%25A2&ei=GK9cUKT7HIWD0QGUvYCwDw&usg=AFQjCNECcwx6NYkqqRQUfVh3Cbw7LARn7w). It is a web service management tool that can manage SOAP or REST WCF-based service across your organization. Further it has a Test Workbench!

Here are a couple of videos that show it off too:

- [Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Meet-SO-Aware-Part-1)
- [Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Meet-SO-Aware-Part-2)

Comment: I evaluated SO-AWARE and frankly didn't like it. Too much settings to be done manually to set a service catalog. The Test workbench has very limited functionality and even the free SOAPUI blows it out of water and SOAPUI PRO is so much better. e.g. There was no way to setup a parameterised test and then drive the parameter values from a csv file etc.

Comment: @Pratik, how long ago did you evaluate SO-AWARE?

Comment: 2 months back and I purchased SOAPUI PRO after evaluating. I was mainly looking for WebService functionality testing and load testing tool.

Comment: Yeah, I think SO-AWARE is going to be the OP's best option because it's capable of giving you an overview of all the web services running in your organization -- and it's capable of pushing configuration to those services as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is something like this in .net. All your services are made of different technologies asmx, wcf, rest ...  and also different business.

First, you have to be able to fully isolate (code, reference, bdd) all these services for testing.

One solution for your problem could **Visual Studio Virtual Labs** : A lab environment is a collection of virtual and physical machines, which you can use to develop and test applications. It can contains multiple roles needed to test multi-tiered applications, such as workstations, web servers, and database servers. You can also use a build-deploy-test workflow with your lab environment to automate the process of building, deploying, and running automated/load tests on your application (full compatible with TFS)

A good start is [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997438.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put a facade web service in front of all the separate web services. It may done programatically as a master pass through service or maybe even possible to use the WCF relay binding for this. I would also suggest taking a look a BizTalk. You should be able to setup canonical web services that maps to internal web services with proper mapping. You can even setup choreographed and orchestrated web service methods that as composed of multiple internal service methods. Security policy and logging can be applied centrally as well.

For testing I would seriously look as using SOAPUI PRO. I am extremely happy with this product. The only disadvantage is that it doesn't suport net.tcp binding. But you can have all your services exposed as basicHttpBinding in a test environment and run the test cases.